# Saving data to local storage in React

Tags: reactjs

So I have those cards on the link right now. When the favorite button is clicked it will appear under **FAVORITES**. I wanted those cards under **FAVORITES** to be on the local storage, and when I "unfavorite" the cards, they should also be removed from the local storage. But how exactly do I do that? Should I use useEffect()?

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-fast-kgyzvc?file=/src/App.js

App.js

```
export default function App() {
  const [all, setAll] = useState(true);
  const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState(false);

  const showAll = () => {
    setAll(true);
    setFavorites(false);
  };
  const showFavorite = () => {
    setFavorites(true);
    setAll(false);
  };

  const [dataSource, setDataSource] = useState(data);

  const onFavorite = (cardId) => {
    const newDataSource = [...dataSource];
    const foundCardData = newDataSource.find((card) => card.id === cardId);
    if (!foundCardData) return;
    foundCardData.isFavorite = !foundCardData.isFavorite;
    setDataSource(newDataSource);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="button-group">
        <button className={all ? "all active" : "all"} onClick={showAll}>
          ALL
        </button>
        <button
          className={favorites ? "favorites active" : "favorites"}
          onClick={showFavorite}
        >
          FAVORITES
        </button>
      </div>
      <br />
      <Masonry
        breakpointCols={3}
        className="my-masonry-grid"
        columnClassName="my-masonry-grid_column"
      >
        {all &&
          dataSource.map((item) => (
            <Cards
              key={item.id}
              text={item.text}
              isFavorite={item.isFavorite}
              onFavorite={() => onFavorite(item.id)}
            />
          ))}
        {favorites &&
          dataSource
            .filter((item) => item.isFavorite === true)
            .map((filtered) => (
              <Cards
                key={filtered.id}
                text={filtered.text}
                isFavorite={filtered.isFavorite}
                onFavorite={() => onFavorite(filtered.id)}
              />
            ))}
      </Masonry>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Cards.js

```
const Cards = ({ text, isFavorite, onFavorite }) => {
  return (
    <div className="cards">
      <p>{text}</p>
      <button onClick={onFavorite}>
        {isFavorite ? "Added to Favorites!" : "Favorite"}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: use hooks/effect on update the dataSource ?     useEffect(() => { localstorage.set("key", JSON.stringly(dataSource)  }, [dataSource]); and as init hook u get the data from localstorage by   useEffect(() => {  setDataSource(JSON.parse(localstorage.get("key"))  }, []);

Comment: I tried it but it's also not working @StefanBD

Comment: You need to think about the logic of storing and retrieving data in your application. Now you are overwriting the local storage with data from "data.js ". Discard "data.js " and work only with local storage or create in local storage a separate array only for the IDs of the favorite elements and display the elements depending on whether there is an element ID in the array or not.